# Fields in UrlFormEncoded post requests are encoded twice

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit, urlencode

I'm trying to send an authentication (login) POST request with retrofit, this is the retrofit service interface:

```
interface AuthApiService {

    @POST("customer/login/")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    suspend fun login(
        @FieldMap(encoded = true) parameters: Map<String, String>,
    ): Customer
}
```

the problem is the fields parameters of the `parameters` map is being URL-Encoded **twice**, for example the email `email@gmail.com` is being sent as `email%2540gmail.com` instead of `email%40gmail.com`.

I tried to set `@FieldMap(encoded = false)` but it is still the same.

I even tried this:

```
@POST("customer/login/")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    suspend fun login(
        @Field("email",encoded = true) email:String,
        @Field("password",encoded = true) password:String
    ): Customer
```

and this:

```
@POST("customer/login/")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    suspend fun login(
        @Field("email",encoded = false) email:String,
        @Field("password",encoded = false) password:String
    ): Customer
```

**But NO LUCK.**

Comment: Can you show, how you are calling `login` function?

Comment: I found the problem in the my request Interceptor class, I'll post the answer. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I the problem was in my request Interceptor class:

```
class BaseRequestInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        var request = chain.request()
        val body = request.body as FormBody

        val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

        with(body) {
            for (x in 0 until size) {
                // ######## here was the problem ########
                map[encodedName(x)] = encodedValue(x)
            }
        }

        // adding universal fields for every request
        map["field_key1"] = "field_value1"
        map["field_key2"] = "field_value2"

        val newFormBody = FormBody.Builder().apply {
            map.forEach {
                add(it.key, it.value)
            }
        }.build()

        request = request.newBuilder().apply {
            post(newFormBody)
        }.build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

}
```

I solved the problem by replacing the line:

```
map[encodedName(x)] = encodedValue(x)
```

with:

```
map[name(x)] = value(x)
```